# List gets updated when Model of EditForm changes. How to prevent?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

In my table, I have a List op type `Person` called `PersonList`. When a row is clicked, another object (Model) of type `Person`, is set to that value of that row, so my `EditForm` gets updated with that value. So far so good.

But when I change te value in my `EditForm`, my List get also updated with that value.

How is that possible? And how to prevet it?

Many thanks!

```
<h3>Component</h3>

<table>
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Age</th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       @foreach (var person in PersonList)
       {
           <tr @onclick="@(() => ActivateItem(person))">
               <td>@person.Id</td>
               <td>@person.Name</td>
               <td>@person.Age</td>
           </tr>
       }
   </tbody>
</table>

<EditForm Model="Model">
    <InputText @bind-Value="Model.Name" />
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="Model.Age" />
</EditForm>


@code {

    private List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();
    private Person Model = new Person();

    private void ActivateItem(Person person)
    {
        Model = person;
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        PersonList.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Jack",
            Age = 20
        });

        PersonList.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "Paul",
            Age = 25
        });

        PersonList.Add(new Person
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "Brad",
            Age = 30
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How? Isn't it a differtent object?

Comment: Is it possible to disable your editform?

Comment: @Inktkiller oh true. I have no idea in that case, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is because you are keeping the reference to the object and bind-value is a two way binding. Not strange at all.

One solution is to use a one way binding and the other solution would be to remove the reference from the object by instansiate a new object. Something like this:

```
private void ActivateItem(Person person)
    {
        Model = new Person
        {
              Id = person.Id,
              Name = person.Name,
              Age = person.Age
         };
    }
```

Comment: The user must be able to change the values in EditForm, so it can not be disabled. It is the List that should not be updated.